# How to use google place api in iphone to query supermarkets around my place

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, google-api

I am new in Google places API and don't know how to use in our application...Can any one explain me how to get the list of Supermarkets around my places..

Currently I am using this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#Introduction) but not able to get that things which I want.

Please help me to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=lat,long&radius=500&types=grocery_or_supermarket&sensor=false&key=yourkey
```